# How to enable autocompleting & syntax highlighting for C/C++ within Android project in intellij IDEA?

Tags: c++, android, autocomplete, android-ndk

I'm starting with Android NDK and would like to write code in Intellij Idea, but I can't find any way to make Idea work with c++ files within Android project in the same way as Java sources (for autocompleting and syntax highliting, and, the most important for debugging). Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure if IntelliJ Idea supports C/C++ (guess it doesn't). But Eclipse + CDT + Sequoyah is very nice for Android NDK development.

http://www.eclipse.org/sequoyah/